# Fitting the background in XCode

Tags: ios, xcode, image

I have a really stupid question...

I'm afraid I'm stuck at the basics, trying to fit a 2732 × 2048 (Read up that this is the resolution for the iPad pro, for which I'm building an app) image, but it doesn't scale no matter what I do. I want it to scale to fit the screen, rather than be beyond the borders of the screen.

I tried playing with the align constraints, but nothing changed no matter what I adjusted...

Thanks in advance!

[image: This...]

Edit: Added an image and described my failure

Comment: You should include what you have tried so far in the question, any code, image (screenshot) if you don't want  a lot of questions in the comments.

Comment: Yes, if you say "no matter what I do", please list what you did, what results you were expecting, and what you got. You may include screenshots if that helps (probably will).

Comment: Updated, sorry for this confusion, didn't recognise that might help I guess. Very sleepy.

Comment: Need a comment padge

Comment: Oops I meant to say badge

Comment: Lol hey I just got it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. drag a UIImageView to the controller in Storyboard.
2. scale it to match the size of view in controller, add some constraints by tap `Editor in menu bar -> Resolve Auto Layout Issues -> Reset to Suggested Constraints`.
3. Set image of UIImageView to you image, set view mode to `Scale to Fit`

I am not familiar with Auto Layout, this may not be the perfect way.

Comment: Thank you, going to try it when I go back home, have a few lectures to attend now!